# How to set fixed height for Card content in Material UI? Should I use CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

this has been driving me crazy. I'm using Material-UI cards to display News. However, I have a problem. In the paragraph section where it's supposed to display a short message about the news article, If the content of the paragraph section takes up two rows of text then the button below it has a spacing in between of around 10px but if the paragraph section takes up 3 lines, then the padding in between of the paragraph section and the button is around 14px.

Here's a picture so you'd easily understand it.

[image]

As you can see, the spacing between the paragraph section and the "Source and View" section varies depending on the amount of lines. Can anyone give any solutions? I tried using CSS to adjust the margins and paddings but it does so to every card so it's the same effect. What I'd like to do is to be able to contain the paragraph in a container that has a fixed height so that the "Source and View" section will always remain in place.

Any suggestions?

Note: Here's a code snippet of the entire Card component:

```
<Card className={classes.newsCard} raised={true}>
                                <CardMedia
                                    component='img'
                                    height='140'
                                    src={NewsInfoArray.image}
                                    title='News Image'
                                />
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography className={classes.companyName}>
                                        {truncateString(NewsInfoArray.headline, 60)}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography className={classes.subheader}>
                                        {truncateString(NewsInfoArray.summary, 130)}
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                                <Grid item container direction='row' justify='space-between' spacing={3} alignItems='center'>
                                    <Grid item>
                                        <CardContent>
                                            <Typography className={classes.subheader}>
                                                Source: {NewsInfoArray.source}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </CardContent>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item >
                                        <CardActions>
                                            <Link target='_blank' rel='noopener' href={NewsInfoArray.url} underline='none'>
                                                <Button
                                                    size='large'
                                                    className={classes.styledButton}
                                                >
                                                    View
                                                </Button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </CardActions>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Flex Box in a column direction and setting the row which contains "source" and "View" to "flex-end"? It's not following the idea of containing the paragraphs in a fixed-height-container, but it would keep that row always at the bottom of the card.

Comment: Yep. The output is still the same.

Comment: I just tried it with inline styling and changing the amount of text inside, it seems to keep the bottom row in the same place no matter what (check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-tu-sp64x?file=/src/App.js) line 16)